# How to call a function on button click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have function and i want to see if the function is getting called or not on button click. I am able to achieve this using js and i see the alert, but i need in jquery.

`<button type="submit" onclick="sendEmail()" id="btnSubmit" formmethod="POST">SUBMIT</button>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("btnSubmit").click(function(){
    alert("Submit button is clicked");
});
```

});

Comment: if you want to select an element with a certain id then you use '#id', what you wrote would select all elements like this: `<btnSubmit ...`

Answer (score 2):

try using the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("Submit button is clicked");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append # sign at the start of Id "btnSubmit".

`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
     alert("Submit button is clicked");
   });
});
```

`

Comment: Thanks this worked. Didn't realize i was missing it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to using the `click()` function is to use `on()` as such:

```
$("#btnSubmit").on('click', function(){
    alert($(this));
})
```